# MySQL AVG() function for all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to return a list the names of each country whose population is larger than the world average population, along with the difference between the world average and that country's population from my database:

The country database is of the form:
Code, Name, Continent, Region, SurfaceArea, IndepYear, Population, LifeExpectancy, GNP, GNPOld, LocalName, GovernmentForm, HeadOfState, Capital, Code2

so far i have come out with this code:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `average_population` AS
    SELECT 
        `country`.`Code` AS `code`,
        `country`.`Name` AS `name`,
        `country`.`Continent` AS `continent`,
        `country`.`Region` AS `region`,
        `country`.`Population` AS `population` 
    FROM
        `country`
    GROUP BY code
    HAVING AVG(population) > (SELECT AVG(Population)
                              FROM country)
```

if i set AVG(population) in the first select statement this just returns only a single record ?

How can i get a  list of the names of each country whose population is larger than the world average population, along with the difference between the world average and that country's population from my database?

Comment: Show us sample data and desire output.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  
  And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: `GROUP BY code` implies that your table has rows with duplicate codes.  That is, that more than one country has the same code.  This doesn't make sense to me.  Does it make sense to your data?

Comment: Are you looking for the average of that country over all time periods (IndepYear) being higher than the average for all countries over all time periods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do it in one line you could use nested selects.

```
SELECT Name, (Population - (SELECT AVG(Population) FROM country)) as 'OverAverage'
FROM country
WHERE Population > (SELECT AVG(Population) FROM country)
```

If possible, it would be much more efficient if you calculated and stored average before hand. That way you would not need to run the average function for every single row.

Comment: @Juan Carlos great information @ Duncan great answer. it works!

Comment: Yes, nested select are usually inefficient, is better calculate the value and perfom a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating the World population in a separated query.

```
SELECT 
    `country`.`Code` AS `code`,
    `country`.`Name` AS `name`,
    `country`.`Continent` AS `continent`,
    `country`.`Region` AS `region`,
    `country`.`Population` AS `population` 
FROM
    `country`
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(Population) AS everyone FROM country) as World
GROUP BY code    
HAVING AVG(population) > World.everyone
```